# customising web.config based on domain name

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Most of my websites include one LIVE (production) and two TEST environments which are accessible via three different domain names e.g.

```
www.mysite.com
test1.mysite.com
test2.mysite.com
```

Each of the above are IIS Websites which point to the same physical **versioned** folder when they are all running the same version of the website.

What I typically do when releasing a new version is to place the new version into a new physical folder e.g. **/inetpub/wwwroot/mywebsite/v41/** and point one of the TEST sites to that version of the site and test it.  Once passed, the LIVE (and other TEST) websites are also repointed to the new version (e.g. v41).

Now my problem is this.  Each website has its own database (TESTs have a copy of LIVE which can be refreshed via a couple of SQL BACKUP/RESTORE commands) however, the three sites are all "looking" at the same web.config file and therefore the same Database Connection Strings (either a System.Data.SqlClient or System.Data.EntityClient provider).

Is there **any** way that I can configure web.config to provide different **connectionStrings** based on the domain name/IIS website of the incoming request?

Maybe a  tag or an attribute that qualifies a given tag?

I've looked all over for a solution but not yet found one.
Thanks in advance,
BloodBaz

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways to manage multiple environment Specific Web.config file....

1. using t4 template,below is the link for that
   http://ilearnable.net/2010/08/02/t4-for-complex-configuration/
2. VS Configuration Manager and create new "LIVE", "test1", "test2" build configurations for your project,check out the link

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/21/tip-trick-automating-dev-qa-staging-and-production-web-config-settings-with-vs-2005.aspx

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

why not split your config file up so connectionStrings.config is its own file.  Then you can deploy everything and not overwrite that connectionString file.

where you normally would put the connectionString do this

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config" />
```

Then create a file named connectionString.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>

</connectionStrings>
```

Alternatively you can create another build option other than just release/debug.  You can have web.config transforms that output a different config file depending on which one is selected.

Comment: This option won't work because as I say, all the websites (domains) point to the same physical folder and hence will all follow the same web.config > configSource > connectionString.config > config string.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem; I solved it by setting up all the database connection info in the same web config file, and then writing a handler that decides on the fly, based on the request and context, which environment it's in and uses that database.